# Put a button on each dynamically generated bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table and I want to place on each dynamic row under the **Tara Image** tab a button with the text let's say "get image". This is the code:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;"><div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3> </div><div class="panel-body">Lists all the missed balance-events entries that need further investigation.</div></div>
                    <table id="scale_missed_entries"
                           data-toggle="table"
                           data-pagination="true" 
                           >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
                <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
                                <th>Tara Image</th>
                             </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I will post a picture with my actual table (I painted with red how I want my buttons to be placed):

[image]

Comment: placed through javascript or native html?

Comment: I would prefer native html

Comment: can you explain dynamic row? I've posted my answer. If that is not what you expect, let me know!

Comment: I posted a comment, basically that rows that you see are generated with some values from a database based on desired user timestamp, so I will have a random number of rows depends of how many entry's I have on that interval.

Comment: for that your question is a server-side question, add the tag for whatever language you're using on the server(and the framework too) and don't forget to include the backend code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var r = document.getElementById('MYTABLE').getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(i=0;i<r.length;i++){
    var td=r[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode(td.innerHTML );       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>

    td.removeChild(td.firstChild);
    td.appendChild(btn);
  }
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;"><div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3> </div><div class="panel-body">Lists all the missed balance-events entries that need further investigation.</div></div>
                    <table id="scale_missed_entries"
                           data-toggle="table"
                           data-pagination="true" 
                           >
                        <thead>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
                <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
                                <th>Tara Image</th>
                             </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody id='MYTABLE'>
                             <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>23.02.2017</td>
                              <td>get image</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                              <td>2</td>
                              <td>23.02.2017</td>
                              <td>get image</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                              <td>3</td>
                              <td>23.02.2017</td>
                              <td>get image</td>
                             </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Uhm, that's for 3 rows only, my rows will be generated in dynamic based on a calendar, I can have 3 rows but I also can have 40, based on user input!